# What's the point of the "is_authenticated" method used in Flask-Login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm working through the Flask Mega-Tutorial right now and I've come across this bit of code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = ROLE_USER)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)
```

is_authenticated, is_active, and is_anonymous seem quite strange to me - when would they ever return anything other than their predefined value?

Could somebody explain to me why Flask-Login makes me use these seemingly useless methods?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all, `is_anonymous()` and `is_authenticated()` are each other's inverse. You could define one as the negation of the other, if you want.

You can use these two methods to determine if a user is logged in.

When nobody is logged in Flask-Login's `current_user` is set to an `AnonymousUser` object. This object responds to `is_authenticated()` and `is_active()` with `False` and to `is_anonymous()` with `True`.

The `is_active()` method has another important use. Instead of always returning `True` like I proposed in the tutorial, you can make it return `False` for banned or deactivated users and those users will not be allowed to login.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, that makes good sense. I didn't realize that current_user could either return an AnonymousUser or a User object. Looking forward to getting the book when it comes out.

Comment: So the proper way to use User.is_authenticated is just return True?

Comment: @thebeancounter for a regular user you should return `True`. This is unlikely needed, but for a user object that represents unauthenticated users, you should return `False`.

Answer (score 10):

I was baffled by this `is_authenticated` vs `is_anonymous` for hours. I could not believe they were just opposite. Finally just by chance I found [this old blog post](http://thegarywilson.com/blog/2006/is_authenticated-vs-is_anonymous/). It is about a problem in the Django templating system in which non existent variables evaluates to `False`. That could lead to wrong behaviour when testing `is_anonymous` in the template code. Again that is old so I don't know if it holds. The way they solved the problem was to create `is_authenticated`.

I guess Flask-Login just copied the model from Django without questioning. Now I can sleep in peace.