# What do flask-login's is_authenticated and is_anonymous do?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

In the documentation, `is_authenticated` is defined as

"is_authenticated:
Returns True if the user is authenticated, i.e. they have provided valid credentials. "

However, I don't understand when this method is called and what its point is, ditto for `is_anonymous`. In the example, they both just return True and False, respectively. What do they do?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is not a duplicate, as the "duplicate" thread does not answer the question that I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not famliar with the lib, but after quick-check the source code:
There are two classes:
`UserMixin` and `AnonymousUserMixin`. 
For `UserMixin` `is_authenticated` is `True` and `is_anonymous` is `False`, and the opposite is for `Anonymous`.

So when you open the application and don't authenticate yourself(current session doesn't have `user_id`, flask-login set user to anonymous user(creates instance of `AnonymousUserMixin`), otherwise it creates an instance of `UserMixin`(I don't think these classes should be called `mixins`, but doesn't matter).

Long story short, depends on authenticated you or not, `user` object created by flask-login will be instanced from the class with appropriate values of `is_authenticated` and `is_anonymous`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the base User class provided from flask. These methods are helpful for writing a decorator that handles "admin" pages that a person must be logged into. calling user.is_anonymous will let you know that a person is not currently logged in, and if they are trying to access a page that requires login access, then your decorator can return a Forbidden message or redirect to the login page.

Calling user.is_authenticated will let you know if the user has entered a successful password and is currently logged into your website.

Additionally a user is always anonymous (an instantiation of the AnonymousUser class) on first loading a page within your app, then when you load the user from the database, the user is an instantiation of the User class. However at this stage they are still unauthenticated. Its not until you do login_user(user) that the user is deemed authenticated.

This is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532372/whats-the-point-of-the-is-authenticated-method-used-in-flask-login)

Comment: When you say "a user is always anonymous on first loading a page", do you mean "first" as in never having visited before?

Comment: Yes. When it is a fresh session